# Отображать тайтл в виде ссылки и первое предложение новости

Tags: post, yii

Поставил стандартную модель Post из папки Demo, захожу в категорию posts, отображаются новости в текстовом виде

айди
тайтл
текст
дата

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы тайтл отображался в виде ссылки, при нажатии на которую был бы заход на отдельную страницу поста, и как сделать, чтобы на этой же странице posts отображалась не вся новость, а только первое ее предложение, а остальное было доступно при заходе на ту отдельную страницу?

Answer (score 2):

> как сделать так, чтобы тайтл отображался в виде ссылки

создать ссылку c помощью [createUrl()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#createUrl-detail) и идентификатора нужного action. Подробнее [здесь](http://yiiframework.ru/doc/guide/ru/topics.url).

> как сделать, чтобы на этой же странице posts отображалась не вся новость, а только первое ее предложение

1. Найти первую точку в посте
2. Вырезать с помощью [substr](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.substr.php) все, что идет до нее
3. Вывести для каждого поста

Comment: Спасибо. Ссылку в тайтле править в PostController в этом участке кода:

    public function actionView($id)
    {
        $this->render('view',array(
            'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
        ));
    }

Если да, то не работает.

Comment: @lekid

> Если да, то не работает.

что, простите?

Comment: Не могли бы Вы мне показать пример кода, который создает создает ссылку с помощью CreateUrl, я не понимаю где этот участок кода находится в yii

Comment: @lekid чаще всего прямо в представлении (`protected/views/post/view.php`). В приведенном коде к этому отсылает только название view, сам он ничего не делает и не выводит (кроме загрузки поста). И вообще, весь вывод происходит внутри view, это один из постулатов mvc.